# nextjs swr hard to use and slow

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I'm using swr to fetch data in a nextjs project, I use the error that useswr hook return to determine

open a dialog or not the problem is the dialog show up very slow take like 2 second.

```
const fetcher = (url:string) =>{
    return axios.get(url).then(res=>res.data)
}


export const useUserInfo = (url:string)=>{


    const {data,error,mutate} = useSWRImmutable<Response,AxiosError>(url,fetcher,{shouldRetryOnError:false})
   


    return {
        data,
        error,
        mutate
    }

}
```

```
const ErrorDialog = (props:Props) =>{


    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const {message,title,handleClick,isError} = props

    useEffect(()=>{

      if(isError!==undefined){
        setOpen(true)
      }

    },[isError])

      const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
      };

    return (

        <>
        <Dialog
        open={open}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
        {title}
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
           {message}
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Disagree</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} autoFocus>
            Agree
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
        
        </>
      
    )


}
```

the ui library I use is mui https://mui.com/

if I just use state to manage the dialog feel like more quickly the dialog show up.And I also have to
mutate the error to undefine when I close dialog and click back button go other page and return to the dialog page otherwise the dialog show twice because the error is not undefine before trigger the new fetch.

Answer (score 0):

I would just set `open={isError}`

No need to `useEffect`. This should also fix manual error resetting.

If it's the initial fetch I suggest to prefetch, then data is available and red from SWR cache for all the `useSWR` (`useUserInfo` in your case) in your project:

https://swr.vercel.app/docs/prefetching